# Can i use openGL on iphone (native) web apps?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I want to build an web app that uses openGL, a native one.
(examples: http://www.apple.com/webapps/index1.html)

I must use openGL and i cannot figure out if i can build a plugin that uses the native openGL component. I do not want it to look as openstreet map or google map in javascript.

What i really want is not simple web app, but a good app, just don't want to go throw the app store.

Can i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari in the iPhone doesn't have WebGL implemented yet so as far as I know there is no way to build webapp which uses WebGL.

Comment: Thanks. but i'm thinking about plugins in objective-C, as you can see in the Apple link i posted, some of the apps are using native components like list, buttons, slides and so on. Can i do that with openGL?